# How to get index and value comparing two arrays which was changed the position and deleted?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays

```
const originalArray= ["form1","form2","form3","form4","form5"];
const modifiedArray = ["form2","additionForm1","form1","form3","additionForm2"];
```

expected results is,

```
let testScript = [form1 is moved to position 2,
                            form2 is moved to position 0,
                            form3 is moved to position 3, 
                            from 4 is deleted position is 3]
                            form5 is deleted position is 4,
                            additional1 added to position 1
                            additional2 added to position 4 
                           ]
```

I can get deleted data using follwing code, But when try to get moved data and position changed data I faced some problem.

this is what I tried,

```
function testFunc(){

  const originalArray = ["form1","form2","form3","form4","form5"];
  const modifiedArray= ["form2","additionForm1","form1","form3","additionForm2"];
  let flag = false;
  let result = [];
  
  originalArray.forEach((Nelement, Nindex) => { 
     
      modifiedArray.forEach((Telement, Tindex) => {
 
            if(Nelement === Telement){ //check originalArray data containg the modified array
              flag = true;
              //return false;
            }
           
            if(flag === true && Nindex !== Tindex){ //try to get moved data
              result.push(Nelement+" change the position to "+ Tindex )
            }
  })
     
      if(flag !== true){ //if original array data doesn't include in modified array
          result.push(Nelement+" removed from "+ Nindex + " position" )
      }
     
        flag = false
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question. This should work and the result is

> "form1 is moved to position 2",
> "form2 is moved to position 0",
> "form3 is moved to position 3",
> "form4 is deleted position is 3",
> "form5 is deleted position is 4",
> "additionForm1 added to position 1",
> "additionForm2 added to position 4"

I use another loop to display the added items to the array

```js
          const originalArray = ["form1","form2","form3","form4","form5"];
  const modifiedArray= ["form2","additionForm1","form1","form3","additionForm2"];
  let flag = false;
  let result = []
  
function testFunc(){
    //Find added items between the two lists
  originalArray.forEach((Nelement, Nindex) => { 
     
      modifiedArray.forEach((Telement, Tindex) => {
 
            if(Nelement === Telement){ //check originalArray data containg the modified array
              flag = true;
           
            if(Nindex !== Tindex)//try to get moved data
              result. push(Nelement+" is moved to position "+ Tindex )
            }
  })
     
      if(!flag){ //if original array data doesn't include in modified array
          result.push(Nelement+" is deleted position is "+ Nindex)
      }
     
        flag = false    
    })
//check added item
let arr = modifiedArray.filter(x => !originalArray.includes(x));
for(let j in arr)
result.push(arr[j]+" added to position "+modifiedArray.indexOf(arr[j]))
console.log(result)
  }
  testFunc()
```

Answer (score 1):

just replace following snippet

```js
if(flag === true && Nindex !== Tindex){ //try to get moved data
              result.push(Nelement+" change the position to "+ Tindex )
            }
```

to

```js
if(Nelement === Telement && Nindex !== Tindex){ //try to get moved data
      result.push(Nelement+" change the position to "+ Tindex )
 }
```

This is because `flag` is not getting unset in the second loop.

complete solution below.

```js
function testFunc(){

  const originalArray = ["form1","form2","form3","form4","form5"];
  const modifiedArray= ["form2","additionForm1","form1","form3","additionForm2"];
  let flag = false;
  let result = [];
  
  originalArray.forEach((Nelement, Nindex) => { 
     
      modifiedArray.forEach((Telement, Tindex) => {
 
            if(Nelement === Telement){ //check originalArray data containg the modified array
              flag = true;
              //return false;
            }
           
            if(Nelement === Telement && Nindex !== Tindex){ //try to get moved data
              result.push(Nelement+" change the position to "+ Tindex )
            }
  })
     
      if(flag !== true){ //if original array data doesn't include in modified array
          result.push(Nelement+" removed from "+ Nindex + " position" )
      }
     
        flag = false;
    })
return result;
  }
```

Comment: This also correct, Thanks for your answer